# alertdialog reusable. unexpected stop

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I'm making an application. I have a button to start an `AlertDialog` and in that dialog, I have an EditText and and "OK" button.

When I run the application first, it works nicely just as I expect it to, but, in same instance, when I push the button which starts the dialog again, it unexpectedly stops.

Why does it do this?

```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    bn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.getdb);
    result = (TextView)findViewById(R.id._result);
    bn2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.txtmsg);

    final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);


    alert.setTitle("id");
    alert.setMessage("ex / 2013");
    final EditText input = new EditText(this);
    alert.setView(input);

    alert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {   
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            String getid = input.getText().toString();

            new HttpTask().execute(getid);    
        }
    });

        bn.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            alert.show();       
        }
    });
```

this code is part of application.

[image]

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace please?

Comment: Where is push button's event associated ? You showed alertdialog in `onCreate` only.

Comment: you do not create AlertDialog and do not show AlertDialog in the code you posted

Comment: i added the button, that showing alertdialog. and post error code